# acts_as_votable gem routes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm new to rails and trying to get upvotes for questions working using the acts_as_votable gem. I am getting the following error telling me i have no route matches:

```
No route matches [GET] "/questions/1/like"
```

Here is my upvote method in my questions_controller.rb:

```
def upvote
@question = Question.find params[:question_id]
@question.liked_by current_user
redirect_to @questions
end
```

My routes.rb file:

```
 resources :comments do
  resources :questions
    member do
    put "like", to: "questions#upvote"
    end
end
```

and my upvote button:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", like_question_path(@comment, @question, method: :put) %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
    put "like", to: "questions#upvote"
  end
end
```

Upvote button:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", comment_question_like_path(@comment, @question), method: :put %>
```

You need the correct path, and also the method for link_to to use goes after the second parameter.

Comment: Great, that works except now i'm getting a "Couldn't find Question with id=like" error and the url skips over the question id. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1):

The path name `like_question_path` is incorrect. It should contain at least "comment", something like "like_comment_question_path". Please consult your `$rake routes` for accurate name.

By the way, is there any reason you need to use `put`? In my opinion this action is not to change existing data but add a new one, so 'POST' should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The method option should be outside of the named route, like this:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", like_question_path(@comment, @question), method: :put %>
```

Also, what @Billy Chan said.