# Upvotes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get upvotes for questions working with the acts_as_votable gem. I am getting an error that says:

```
Couldn't find Question with id=like
```

This URL doesn't show the question id:

```
/comments/1/questions//like
```

and when I manually enter a question id it gives me this:

```
No route matches [GET]
```

Here is my upvote method:

```
def upvote
@question = Question.find params[:question_id]
@question.liked_by current_user
redirect_to @questions
end
```

Here is the routes.rb file:

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
    put :upvote, :on => :member, :as => :like
  end
end
```

and the upvote button:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", comment_question_like_path(@comment, @question), method: :post %>
```

Rake routes shows comment_question_like_path as a valid route so that is not the issue.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you have method: post i your view? I think it should be method: put ..in your routes you specify the put..

Comment: Oops, no reason. Changed the view and forgot to change the route.

Comment: again, in what page you have this link? `/posts` or `/comments/2/questions` ?

Comment: The link is at /comments/2/questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are saying you are on page `/comments/2/questions`, that means you are on `questions#index` action where you load all questions for current comment, and you do a loop through all questions with `@questions.each do |question|` so your link for each question should look like:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", comment_question_like_path(@comment, question) %>
```

and not:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", comment_question_like_path(@comment, @question) %>
```

as you don't have `@question` variable available, that's why you have `/comments/1/questions//like` and question param is not set, should be:
 `/comments/1/questions/5/like`.

**Edit**

---

the way it worked for me in my app, **routes**:

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
    member do
      get :upvote
    end
  end
end
```

**link**:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", comment_question_upvote_path(@comment, question) %>
```

they way you built routes you would need to specify `method: post` to the link.

Comment: Alright, that worked except for now i am getting a "No route matches [GET] "/comments/13/questions/14/upvote" error. I changed comment_question_like_path to like_comment_question_path. Here is what it looks like when i rake routes:"like_comment_question PUT    /comments/:comment_id/questions/:id/upvote(.:format) questions#upvote". Thanks again for the help!

Comment: link should go to `like_comment_question_path(@comment, question)`

Comment: Yep i changed it to "<%= link_to "Upvote", comment_question_like_path(@comment, question) %>" but am still getting the no route matches error.

Comment: path is wrong, read carefully `like_comment_question` not `comment_question_like`

Comment: post the part from routes file where you build this link path.

Answer (score 0):

A follow up from here: [acts_as_votable gem routes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754397/acts-as-votable-gem-routes-error/18759493)

I'm sorry, don't think I fully understood before, try this now:

routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
     member do
        post "like", to: "questions#upvote"
     end
  end
end
```

in your upvote method (assuming questions and comments are related in the model)

```
def upvote
  @question = Question.find params[:id]
  @question.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to comment_question_path(@question.comment, @question)
end
```

and then in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", like_comment_question_path(@comment, @question), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers! Unfortunately still getting a 'no route matches' error.

Comment: can you provide part of the stack trace? on a gist maybe?

Comment: i guess also one question as well would be what does the output of `<%= @comment.inspect %>` and `<%= @question.inspect %>` look like on the view? Do they both have ids?

Comment: Yep they both have id's. I'm not sure but does the fact that they are being upvoted on the question_index page matter? I put the upvote link on the question_show page but then it skips over the comment id and shows the question id.

Comment: what do you mean by skips over the comment id? So when you hover over the link that is generated with my code above, what does it show?

Comment: Your code shows the comment id, user id etc associated with each question and also shows the question id so that's not the problem. I just mean the URL shows "/comments//questions/2" so there is a routing error.

Comment: I see, this would indicate that the `@question.id` is indeed nil, let's move to chat I can help you figure this out. Paste me the output of `@questions.inspect`

Comment: I guess i need more karma to access chat so here is the @questions.inspect output: #<Question id: 7, body: "Hello", comment_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-11 20:51:07", updated_at: "2013-09-11 20:51:07", title: "hello">. '@question.inspect' however, returns just nil for all the questions. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

In your routes

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
   put :upvote, :on => :member, :as => :like
  end
end
```

In your view

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", like_comment_question_path(@comment, @question), method: :put %>
```

In your controller

```
def upvote
  @question = Question.where('id = ? and comment_id = ?', params[:id], params[:comment_id]).first
  unless @question.blank? 
    @question.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to comment_question_path(params[:comment_id], @question)
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Question not found'
    redirect_to comment_questions_path(params[:comment_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am now getting a "Couldn't find Question with id=upvote" error. The url looks like this: /comments/1/questions//upvote

Comment: @user2759575, /comments/1/questions//upvote is coming, because question is nil here. SO in this view's action, first you need to check question is blank? or not, then you need to proceed

Comment: Hi Bachan, thanks for the answer. I checked and question is nil but i'm not sure what to do now. Do have any ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: Can you share your controller code where you are fetching the question? there you need to redirect the page to some where if you find your question is nil.

Comment: Do you mean my index function? If so here it is: def index
    '@comment = Comment.find params[:comment_id]
    '@questions = @comment.questions
  end