# Displaying the last posts image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show the image belonging to the last post at the top of my page
with this code:

```
<%= image_tag @postlast.last.image %>
```

Instead it shows the correct image but beside every post.

My index function looks like this:

```
def index
@posts = Post.order("created_at desc")
@postlast = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
end
```

Here is the full view:

```
 <%= image_tag @postlast.last.image %>

 <%= div_for(post) do %>

 <div class="description">
  <%= link_to (post.title), post %>
 </div>      

 <div class="description2">
 <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago

 <div class="floatright">
  #Questions #Answers
 </div>
 </div>

 <% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question seems to be about positioning, which sounds like an html/css issue. Is there something you suspect is wrong with your rails code instead? Otherwise, we'd need to see the html code that is giving you a bad result and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Well even when i delete all html from the view and have just the image_tag line it still shows 2 pictures for the 2 posts so i suspect it has something to do with my posts_controller telling it to show the image for all posts.

Comment: can you show your view code?

Comment: I ended up getting this one working on my own. However i still cant seem to get upvotes working (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795141/upvotes-not-working) if you are willing to help :)